# Ubuntu 16.4 not recognising on-board graphics for 8th gen mobo Gigabyte Z370M

Tags: 16.04, intel-graphics

With Ubuntu 16.4.3 installed on a new machine with 8th gen CPU/mobo, Ubuntu doesn't seem to be recognising the "graphics". I'm using the on-board graphics, not a separate card. In more detail...

The mobo is Gigabyte Z370M D3H, CPU is Intel S1151 Core i3 8350K. There are two screen ports at the back of the motherboard: DVI-D and HDMI. Only the HDMI one works. The DVI-D port, if connected, has the monitor indicating "no signal".

Also, The HDMI'd screen refreshes really slowly. You can see the refresh-wave come down the screen, about half a second. In the launcher bar, when an icon zooms into or out of existence, it does so in about five clunky discrete jumps. It's usable for configuring, but not for any form of sustained work.

The Ubuntu "Screen Display" Settings window describes the monitor as "Built-in Display", whereas on my old & healthy Ubuntu box, it knows the brand names of the monitors.

The monitors are (dual) ViewSonic VX2703mh-LED. They are working fine under Ubuntu 16.4 with older hardware.

Is this a common problem? Are there drivers I need to install?

LATER

```
guy@Fractal17:~$ sudo lshw -C display
  *-display UNCLAIMED     
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
guy@Fractal17:~$
```

Comment: `sudo lshw -C display` would start to help.

Comment: I got the same with Z370N Wifi + i7-8700

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! Using the on-board graphics seems to have been the problem. Multiple suggestions to use-a-graphics-card were received. I borrowed an old card from a friend, put it in, computer works fine now.

Bigger picture, hardware seems to be getting unfriendly to Linux. One example - I bought a laptop to install Linux on - it just wouldn't install. Apparently, for security reasons, some CPUs/mobos/something won't run an OS unless it's got a magic key. I never verified this, but it matched my experience.